# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los puntos que le corresponden a cada jugador se muestren bien en el archivo?

Tags: c

Estoy por terminar un codigo sobre un juego y en un punto es necesario que el puntaje tras realizar el juego se muestre en un archivo de texto con la fecha y hora, y los puntajes de cada uno de los jugadores. En mi caso, comparo los puntos manualmente desde la consola y los puntos del archivo y no son iguales.
Este es mi codigo:
Esto recibe la funcion, el nombre del archivo lo ingreso en el main como primer linea:
`guardarPuntajes(puntos, 4 , NombreArchivo);`

```
void guardarPuntajes(int* puntajes, int numJugadores, const char* nombreArchivo)
{
    time_t tiempoActual;
    time(&tiempoActual);
    struct tm* fechaHora = localtime(&tiempoActual);
    char fecha[100];

    strftime(fecha, sizeof(fecha), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", fechaHora);

    FILE* archivo = fopen(nombreArchivo, "a");
    if (archivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo de registro.\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(archivo, "Fecha y hora: %s\n", fecha);

    for (int i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++)
    {
        fprintf(archivo, "Jugador %d: %d puntos\n", i + 1, puntajes[i]);
    }

    fprintf(archivo, "\n");

    fclose(archivo);
}
```

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que me imprime en consola:
Fichas disponibles:
[0|0] [0|1] [0|2] [0|3] [0|4] [0|5] [0|6] [1|1] [1|2] [1|3] [1|4] [1|5] [1|6] [2|2] [2|3] [2|4] [2|5] [2|6] [3|3] [3|4] [3|5] [3|6] [4|4] [4|5] [4|6] [5|5] [5|6] [6|6]

Turno del jugador 4
Valores de los dados: 3 1
Opciones:

1. Tomar la ficha con el valor de cada dado
2. Tomar la ficha con la suma de los dos valores
3. Pasar turno
   2
   Jugador 4, elige una ficha disponible con la suma 4: 5
   Fichas disponibles:
   [0|0] [0|1] [0|2] [0|3] [0|5] [0|6] [1|1] [1|2] [1|3] [1|4] [1|5] [1|6] [2|2] [2|3] [2|4] [2|5] [2|6] [3|3] [3|4] [3|5] [3|6] [4|4] [4|5] [4|6] [5|5] [5|6] [6|6]

Turno del jugador 3
Valores de los dados: 6 2
Opciones:

1. Tomar la ficha con el valor de cada dado
2. Tomar la ficha con la suma de los dos valores
3. Pasar turno
   2
   Jugador 3, elige una ficha disponible con la suma 8: 22
   Fichas disponibles:
   [0|0] [0|1] [0|2] [0|3] [0|5] [0|6] [1|1] [1|2] [1|3] [1|4] [1|5] [1|6] [2|2] [2|3] [2|4] [2|5] [2|6] [3|3] [3|4] [3|5] [3|6] [4|5] [4|6] [5|5] [5|6] [6|6]

Turno del jugador 1
Valores de los dados: 1 4
Opciones:

1. Tomar la ficha con el valor de cada dado
2. Tomar la ficha con la suma de los dos valores
3. Pasar turno
   2
   Jugador 1, elige una ficha disponible con la suma 5: 5
   Fichas disponibles:
   [0|0] [0|1] [0|2] [0|3] [0|6] [1|1] [1|2] [1|3] [1|4] [1|5] [1|6] [2|2] [2|3] [2|4] [2|5] [2|6] [3|3] [3|4] [3|5] [3|6] [4|5] [4|6] [5|5] [5|6] [6|6]

Turno del jugador 2
Valores de los dados: 2 2
Opciones:

1. Tomar la ficha con el valor de cada dado
2. Tomar la ficha con la suma de los dos valores
3. Pasar turno
   1
   Jugador 2, elige una ficha disponible con el valor 2: 12

*** Al final si menciona que jugador es el ganador en la consola y si es el que corresponde***

Todos los puntos están revueltos y no corresponden a su jugador.
Así se muestra en el archivo: Lo que esta entre paréntesis yo lo agregue ahorita, eso no aparece en el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que ves en consola y lo que ves en el archivo?

Comment: Esta bien, ya edito la pregunta

Comment: Estás asumiendo que el error se encuentra en una función que no manipula datos de ninguna manera ... solo los muestra. Dices que los valores del fichero no concuerdan con los de la consola ... pero no muestras el código de la consola. No tenemos nada para comparar. Yo te sugiero intentar eliminar código innecesario hasta conseguir un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema y volver por aquí con ese código. En cualquier caso todo apunta a que el error no está en la función que has puesto en esta pregunta